# as3 - How do you define a movieclip's parent's parent from another class?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to call a movieclip's parent's parent from a class.

I can however define the object's parent, but when I try to use the parent's parent, it gives me an error.

Adding the parent to the object is like this:

```
MovieClip(parent).object
```

Adding the parent's parent gives me an error:

```
MovieClip(parent.parent).object
```

So could someone give me tips on how to call a MovieClip's parent's parent the correct way?

Comment: try `(this.parent.parent as MovieClip)`

Comment: I suggest to not try this at all. The parent keyword is bad in almost all cases. I don't even have words for parent.parent. When you need to access an object up in the display tree use events or delegation or callbacks.

Comment: Perhaps update your question with what you are actually trying to accomplish and a more appropriate solution can be given.    Also, what error are you receiving? It's good to include these things when you ask a question.

Comment: I found that irrelevent to the issue so I chose not to add it. I just want to find a way to define a movieclip's parent's parent. Not to fix any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, although as stated by others is definitely a bad practice, seems you need to

```
Movieclip(MovieClip(parent).parent).object;
```

You could also:

```
((parent as MovieClip).parent as MovieClip).object;
```